# Graph query - where out vs select expand

Tags: orientdb

Is one of those solutions objectively better, or it all depends on the data? Explain option shows me that indeed, the optimizer does the query differently. This is just an example, I'm going to have lot's of such queries in my application, and I want to know the best way to perform such filtering.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT expand(in('hasPermission')) 
     FROM Permission 
     WHERE type IN ['USER']) 
WHERE 
    login >="admin" 
ORDER BY 
    login ASC
LIMIT 3

SELECT * 
FROM User 
WHERE login >= "admin" 
  AND out("hasPermission").type IN ["USER"] 
ORDER BY login ASC 
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the domain. Consider that the query optimizer in v 2.2 just starts scanning (or querying an index on) the target class (Permission in the first query, User in the second one) and then proceeds with traversing.

The first query is more efficient if you have few Permission records that have "USER" in `type` attribute and if the number of incoming edges per permission is low. Even better if you have an index on `type`

The second query is more efficient if you have few users with `login` > "admin" (again, with an index likely) and if the number of outgoing edges per single user is low.

Comment: Thats kind of what I suspected. Thanks for explaining the inner workings of query optimizer - that makes your answer much more valuable.

Comment: Oh, I've also learned this is called pivoting the query. For the second query, is it possible to create composite index that would fit this kind of query?

Comment: No, unfortunately indexes on "connected" elements are not used in this case. ie. an index on Permission.type won't be used in the second query